# Stack level too deep error after running bundle update

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app which run fine for some months. However, yesterday, after I've run bundle update, I cannot start server anymore. Whenever I start webrick it raises this error:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

I don't know which cause this base on the above error message.

Also this is my gemfile:
[Gemfile](http://paste2.org/dKwHKPt0)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that occurs to me at the moment is to rollback to where the app was running and try to update one gem at a time. This way you will find which one is causing the issue and we may help you from there.

Comment: I rolled back to old state and decided to keep it that way. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I tested your Gemfile and, as I thought, there seems to be conflict with your gems, specifically between *rest-open-uri* and *paperclip*. Depending on how much you are using *rest-open-uri* in your program, it may be worth it to switch to another HTTP library. There are a lot of [Ruby HTTP libraries](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) out there.